# React Testing Library How to spyOn AgGrid APIs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ag-grid, react-testing-library, ag-grid-react

I have a basic react component with a simple AgGrid. Below the grid i have added some buttons that call an AgGrid API example download to CSV:

```
const GridExample = () => {
    const api = useRef(null);
    const containerStyle = { width: '100%', height: '100%' };

    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
       { date: '12/12/2022  3:00PM' },
       { date: '10/31/2022  7:00PM' },
       { date: '10/30/2022  7:00AM' },
       { date: '10/1/2022  8:00AM' },
       { date: '8/31/2022  4:59PM' },
    ]);  

    const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
        { field: 'date' },
    ]);

    const gridReady = (params) => {
        api.current = params?.api;
        api.current.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }

    const csv = () => {
        api.current.exportDataAsCsv({
            filename: new Date()
        });
    }

    return (
        <div style={containerStyle}>
            <div style={containerStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine">
               <AgGridReact
                   rowData={rowData}
                   columnDefs={columnDefs}
                   onGridReady={gridReady}
               ></AgGridReact>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button onClick={csv}>CSV</button>
    );
};
```

In my test, i can assert that the grid is rendered, but i am struggling to mock the `api` and the `exportDataAsCsv` method so i can assert that they are called on `<button>` click.

Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { act, render, screen, fireEvent, RenderResult, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { GridExample } from './GridExample';

const waitForGridToBeInTheDOM=()=>{
    return waitFor(() => {
        expect(document.querySelector(".ag-root-wrapper")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
}

describe('GridTest', () => {
    it('should expect date grid to render with Date column', async function () {
        let grid;
        await act( async () => {
            grid = render(<GridExample/>);
        });

        await waitForGridToBeInTheDOM();

        expect(screen.getByText('Date')).toBeInTheDocument();

        let btn = screen.getByText(/CSV/i);
        fireEvent.click(btn);

        // ..expect(api.export to CSV ).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: pretty sure you won't be able to mock this. Or if you do you might need to jump through hoops. Have you considered alternatives? Instead of mocking API you have some toast with confirmation messages and use `waitFor` to see when a message appears.

Comment: I agree with pavlovic, you should not mock but test a visual feedback instead

Comment: How would i set a mock implementation of the agGrid api on gridReady?

Comment: Have you tried what they suggest from their docs about testing https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/testing/ ?

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, for testing to be meaningful you should not check for detail implementations. Instead, you should test your code from the point of view of the user. This strategy will give you more confidence if in the future you change the implementation but maintain the functionalities, since your tests will continue to pass.

With that in mind your current test relies in two detail implementations:

1. The grid is going to be loaded when the class `.ag-root-wrapper` is in the document.
2. When exporting the `exportDataAsCsv` of agGrid is called.

As an alternative, to avoid those you could:

1. Disable your button until the necessary setup has been done.
2. Show the user some feedback that the export has taken place.

Following those principles you could have two additional states in your component, like:

```
const GridExample = () => {
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

    const api = useRef(null);
    const containerStyle = { width: '100%', height: '100%' };

    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
       { date: '12/12/2022  3:00PM' },
       { date: '10/31/2022  7:00PM' },
       { date: '10/30/2022  7:00AM' },
       { date: '10/1/2022  8:00AM' },
       { date: '8/31/2022  4:59PM' },
    ]);  

    const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
        { field: 'date' },
    ]);

    const gridReady = (params) => {
        setDisabled(false);
        api.current = params.api;
        api.current.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }

    const csv = () => {
        api.current.exportDataAsCsv({
            filename: new Date()
        });
        setMessage('Data exported as CSV');
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div style={containerStyle}>
                <div style={containerStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine">
                    <AgGridReact
                        rowData={rowData}
                        columnDefs={columnDefs}
                        onGridReady={gridReady}
                    ></AgGridReact>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button disabled={disabled} onClick={csv}>CSV</button>
            {message && <p>{message}</p>}
        </>
    );
};
```

And then your test would look like:

```
const waitForGridToBeReady = (grid) => {
    const button = grid.getByText(/CSV/i);
    return waitFor(() => {
        expect(button).not.toBeDisabled();
    });
};

describe('GridTest', () => {
    it('should expect date grid to render with Date column', async function () {
        const grid = render(<GridExample />);
        await waitForGridToBeReady(grid);

        expect(grid.getByText('Date')).toBeInTheDocument();

        // This mock is necessary because it is used to export and it is not defined in jsdom library.
        window.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn();
        const btn = screen.getByText(/CSV/i);
        fireEvent.click(btn);

        expect(grid.getByText('Data exported as CSV')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Of course the message could be a toast or something similar, that disappears after a few seconds.

**Alternative: Coupling your tests with the implementations**

If you still want to go for the route of testing implementation... You could always change your GridExample component so that it exposes a reference to the agGrid api:

```
const GridExample = React.forwardRef((_, ref) => {
    const api = useRef(null);
    const containerStyle = { width: '100%', height: '100%' };

    React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        return api.current;
    });

    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
        { date: '12/12/2022  3:00PM' },
        { date: '10/31/2022  7:00PM' },
        { date: '10/30/2022  7:00AM' },
        { date: '10/1/2022  8:00AM' },
        { date: '8/31/2022  4:59PM' },
    ]);  

    const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
        { field: 'date' },
    ]);

    const gridReady = (params) => {
        api.current = params.api;
        api.current.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }

    const csv = () => {
        api.current.exportDataAsCsv({
            filename: new Date()
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div style={containerStyle}>
                <div style={containerStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine">
                    <AgGridReact
                        rowData={rowData}
                        columnDefs={columnDefs}
                        onGridReady={gridReady}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>

            <button disabled={isDisabled} onClick={csv}>CSV</button>
        </>
    );
});
```

And then you can access the reference:

```
const waitForGridApiToBeReady = ref => {
    return waitFor(() => {
        return expect(ref.current).not.toBeNull();
    });
}

describe('GridTest', () => {
    it('should expect date grid to render with Date column', async function () {
        const ref = React.createRef();
        const grid = render(<GridExample ref={ref}/>);

        await waitForGridApiToBeReady(ref);

        expect(screen.getByText('Date')).toBeInTheDocument();

        ref.current.exportDataAsCsv = jest.fn();
        const btn = screen.getByText(/CSV/i);
        fireEvent.click(btn);

        expect(ref.current.exportDataAsCsv).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```